# Error message won't show up when putting wrong username

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase database for my app project, but I don't understand why when I put the wrong username the error message won't show up. The progress bar just keep looping. But when I put the wrong password the error message shows up. The only way to start the main activity is by putting both password and username correctly. How can the error message show when the user miss the username or password?

My Login Activity

```
        Query query = databaseReference.child("Users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(userName.getText().toString().trim());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Users usersBean = user.getValue(Users.class);

                        if (usersBean.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString().trim()) && usersBean.getUsername().equals(userName.getText().toString().trim())) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "" +
                                    "Login successful " + ("\ud83d\ude03") + "! " + "Well welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            textLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "" +
                                    "Login failed " + ("\ud83d\ude15") + "! " + " Wrong Username or Password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            textLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

My User Class

```
 public class Users {
   private String id;
   private String password;
   private String username;
public Users() {
}

public Users(String email, String id, String password, String username) {

    this.id = id;
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getUsername() {

    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to create a sign-in system, Firebase Authentication is much easier and more secure than trying to create something yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query searchs for records equal to the username.
if you write a wrong username, the query returns no data.
For this reason "for-loop" part doesn't work. Thus, "if-else" part doesn't work.

On the other hand, if you enter a valid username and wrong password,
your query returns a record. Then "else" part shows message.

Try this.

```
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
            {
                //for loop here
            }
            else
            {
                //Your error message
            }
```